# Haystack Multiple Indices - indexed same even there are different search_indexes

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I have the following search

```
class ProductIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    destination = indexes.FacetIntegerField(
        model_attr='hotel__destination__id')
    country = indexes.FacetIntegerField(model_attr='hotel__country__id')
    hotel_class = indexes.FacetCharField(model_attr='hotel__hotel_class')
    hotel_type = indexes.FacetIntegerField(model_attr='hotel__hotel_type__id')


    def get_model(self):
        return Product

    def index_queryset(self, using=True):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()



class DestinationIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    content_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr="foo")
```

And following settings in settings.py

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE':
        'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
    },
    'autocomplete': {
        'ENGINE':
        'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'autcomplete',
    }
}
```

But when I say rebuild_indexes, two index become the same, they index according to both index classes. But I want default index to be indexed with ProductIndex and autocomplete to be indexed with Destination index.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can exclude indexes using key `EXCLUDED_INDEXES`:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE':
        'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
        'EXCLUDED_INDEXES': ['my_destination_app.search_indexes.DestinationIndex'],
    },
    'autocomplete': {
        'ENGINE':
        'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'autcomplete',
        'EXCLUDED_INDEXES': ['my_product_app.search_indexes.ProductIndex'],
    }
}
```