# Django haystack multiple models

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm using django-haystack on a project with several app. So I have a search_indexes.py in an app and another search_indexes.py that is in the same project.

```
project
 ├── app
 │    ├── search_indexes.py
 │
```

├── app2
         ├── search_indexes.py

My two indexes are relatively easy and I have the same problem:

[Haystack Multiple Indices - indexed same even there are different search_indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233752/haystack-multiple-indices-indexed-same-even-there-are-different-search-indexes)

in elasticsearch both are mersed all, I can not distinguish them in my results and more I feel that it is one of the two, as both are well indexed in elsticsearch, I do not know
how. When I make a build_index:

```
Your choices after this are to restore from backups or rebuild via the `rebuild_index` command.
Are you sure you wish to continue? [y/N] y
Removing all documents from your index because you said so.
All documents removed.
Indexing 25 custom forms  
Indexing 12 articles
```

All is well indexed, I love that he seeks in both index and can distinguish.

Thanks

Comment: I have posted an answer to this question [Haystack Multiple Indices - indexed same even there are different search_indexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233752/haystack-multiple-indices-indexed-same-even-there-are-different-search-indexes/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am definitely a little misspoke because my problem is still a little different. I'd just be sure that by default it looks in different models geared especially to distinguish which model is the data found. But thanks again.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question then? I am still confused what is your actual problem. Perhaps an example would be great to explain it further.

Comment: Maybe index each data app in different index ? Like have one index called app1 and another called app2, when you do a query over 2 indexes it's just one query over more shards (if you need to do query to both indexes)